# Calculated field not displaying data-reports devexpress

Tags: c#, report, expression, devexpress, calculated-field

I have many calculated fields in my report. I have set Datsource and datamember and given field type and dragged the field into report. On running data is not showing up.

Expression given is:
Iif([Mode]==0,[NetAmt], 0)

where NetAmt is field in table.
I have some fields populated through designer and some fields through code.

Could you help to solve the problem

Comment: I have set datasource and datamember of calculated fields through designer. When I gave it through code it worked. Its beacuse I am setting datasource and datamember of report through designer aswell as code because data connection should be determined at run time only whther integrated security or not. But its a tedious task to set each calculated field datasource and datamember through code. Is there a way to set all together.

Comment: We can take report.calculatedfields.count  and assign datsource and datamember by iterating thru loop.                                                                                                                  Nowadays help is not getting from stack overflow. Please look into this.